# Maintain User Experience in iOS when frequently updating PHP scripts and MYSQL tables

Tags: php, ios, mysql, versioning, updating

I'm wondering of someone knows a good strategy to prevent crashing or forcing the user to update the app, when I'm updating php files to which the app connects. There will always be some people who won't update my app, so if they send a request to my server the old iOS app won't correlate with the new php scripts?

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different versions of your php server apis. When making a change just increase the version and leave the old implementation to the old version.